# Blur mirror shader

Tags: opengl-es, three.js, opengl-es-2.0

Does anyone know how I can apply Guassian Blur to a mirror texture?
I just want to apply the blur to one texture and not the entire scene which I tried already with postprocessing dof.

In my fragment shader, I cannot figure how to blur the result of my texture2DProj.
For example, if I had the following line:

```
uniform sampler2D mirrorMap;
varying vec4 mirrorCoord;
void main(){
    mColor = texture2DProj(mirrorMap, mirrorCoord);
    gl_FragColor = mcolor;
}
```

How can I do something similar like the following:

```
vec4 sum = vec4( 0.0 );
float v = 1.0 / 250.0 ;
sum += texture2D( baseTexture, vec2( vUv.x, vUv.y - 4.0 * v ) ) * 0.051;
sum += texture2D( baseTexture, vec2( vUv.x, vUv.y - 3.0 * v ) ) * 0.0918;
..etc

gl_FragColor = sum;
```

Comment: You are aware that `textureProjOffset (...)` exists, correct? If you're trying to do a Gaussian blur, then you want to fetch a window of texels and then pass that through your filter kernel. That function will let you directly offset 1 texel at a time and it should be the most intuitive solution. My only concern is your OpenGL version, which is pretty hard to figure out from all of your tags - `textureProjOffset (...)` was introduced in GL 3.0 (GLSL 1.30).

Comment: I'm doing this with threejs which I think is based on opengl es 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm doing this with threejs which I think is based on opengl es 2.0.

Oh, okay. Well this should be fairly simple even without `textureProjOffset (...)`.

All `texture<1|2|3>DProj (...)` actually does is automatically divide the first three coordinates by the 4<sup>th</sup> coordinate before doing the texture lookup. In the case of `texture2DProj` this means:

```
st' = (stpq.s / stpq.q, stpq.t / stpq.q)
// The input coordinates had a 3rd coordinate but it's not used for anything in 2D
```

#### Thus,  you can substitute `texture2DProj (...)` with `texture2D (...)` like so:

```
uniform sampler2D mirrorMap;
varying vec4 mirrorCoord;

void main(){
    vec2 unproj2D = vec2 (mirrorCoord.s / mirrorCoord.q,
                          mirrorCoord.t / mirrorCoord.q);

    mColor = texture2D(mirrorMap, unproj2D);
    gl_FragColor = mcolor;
}
```

Then you can apply the same sort of logic as you did in your original question, because now you have simple 2D coordinates rather than 4D homogeneous coordinates.